# how to move or pan scene such a way that object will come to center using threejs?

Tags: 3d, three.js, pan

I have scene like this, that uses an orthogonal camera:

[image: Camera image before clicking on an object]

As shown in the image when I click on an object circled by white color, I want to rotate the camera or pan the camera in such a way that object will come to center of the screen, and that it will look like the following:

[image: Camera image after clicking an object]

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use orbit controls, set orbit control's target to this object position. That's it.

Comment: Yep correct, I am trying to get the 2D coordinates of screen for an object. and then After some addition subtraction like below, pan the object for that (x,y).
`vector.setFromMatrixPosition(object.matrixWorld);
vector.project(camera);
vector.x = vector.x * widthHalf  ;    
vector.y = -(vector.y * heightHalf) ;
x = -vector.x;
y = -vector.y;
OrbitControl.pan(x, y);` But still this is not working correctly. If object is not in screen visible area then its problem.